Create an interface class module in Excel VBA for the CommandButtons of a userform
I would like to create an interface class module in Excel VBA for the CommandButtons of a userform. The click events should be executed in the class. Can anyone help me with this? Somehow I can't do it
Many thanks
My code so far:
Class Interface: iButtonInterface
Sub oFormButton_Click()
End Sub

Class: clsSaveButton
Implements iButtonInterface

Private WithEvents oFormButton As MsForms.CommandButton

Sub iButtonInterface_oFormButton_Click()
    ' Code if cmdSave-Button on userform is clicked
    MsgBox "Save Button clicked!" & oFormButton
End Sub

Code Userform1
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ctrl   As Control

    ' Initialize Button-Class
    Dim oButton As iButtonInterface

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        Select Case ctrl.Name
            Case "cmdSave"
                Set oButton = New clsSaveButton
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next ctrl
End Sub


Are you getting an error of any sort?  If so, what is it and what lines does it occur on?

As soon as UserForm_Initialize completes, your oButton goes out of scope and can't capture any events.  That needs to be declared as a Global or at least Static.

...also your code doesn't assign your class variable oFormButton to anything.

I wanted to create a separate class for each user form button.
It is already failing because the iButtonInterface implementation is displayed as an error


I wanted to create a separate class for each user form button. It is already failing because the iButtonInterface implementation is displayed as an error

I guess that there is a problem with the name you gave to the sub click in the button interface. Try just without underscore:

Interface IButton
Besides your click handler it needs a way how to bind the real form  button to your button, here as set property

Option Explicit

Public Sub oFormButtonClick()
    Err.Raise 123456789, , "Used as interface only. Implement in class"
End Sub

Public Property Set FormButton(ByVal vNewValue As MSForms.CommandButton)
    Err.Raise 123456789, , "Used as interface only. Implement in class"
End Property

Public Property Let SheetName(ByVal vNewValue As String)
    Err.Raise 123456789, , "Used as interface only. Implement in class"
End Property

Public Property Get SheetName() As String
    Err.Raise 123456789, , "Used as interface only. Implement in class"
End Property


Class clsSaveButton
Implements the interface and just redirects the click event to your button

Option Explicit

Implements IButton

Private WithEvents oFormButton As MSForms.CommandButton
Private m_sheetName As String

Private Property Set IButton_FormButton(ByVal vNewValue As MSForms.ICommandButton)
    Set oFormButton = vNewValue
End Property

Private Sub IButton_oFormButtonClick()
    ' Code if cmdSave-Button on userform is clicked
    MsgBox "Save Button clicked! " & oFormButton.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub oFormButton_Click()
    Call IButton_oFormButtonClick
End Sub

Private Property Let IButton_SheetName(ByVal vNewValue As String)
    m_sheetName = vNewValue
End Property

Private Property Get IButton_SheetName() As String
    IButton_SheetName = m_sheetName
End Property


Form
Declares private variable of type of your button interface and instantiates an object of your button wrapper class.
Sets reference to real form button inside of your wrapper

Option Explicit

Private oButtonSave As IButton
Private oButtonDelete As IButton

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ' Initialize Button-Class
    Dim ctrl   As Control

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        Select Case ctrl.Name
            Case "cmdSave"
                Set oButtonSave = New clsSaveButton
                Set oButtonSave.FormButton = ctrl
                Let oButtonSave.SheetName = Worksheets(1).CodeName
            Case "cmdDelete"
                ' TODO: create clsDeleteButton which implements IButton
                ' Set oButtonDelete = New clsDeleteButton
                ' Set oButtonDelete.FormButton = ctrl
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next ctrl

    MsgBox "Sheet name of save button is : " & oButtonSave.SheetName

End Sub


Thank you for your answer. This also works perfectly for the btnSave. If I create another button e.g. btnDelete then only the last button works. why is that?

When you declare buttons in your form e.g like this : Private oButtonSave As IButton, Private oButtonDelete As IButton and then inside of the For Each loop you create the instances of your buttons, like : Case "cmdSave" Set oButtonSave ... Case "cmdDelete" Set oButtonDelete ... then it should work. If not just edit your question and show your latest code. HTH

Everything works perfectly.
How can I pass on the name/code name of a worksheet to the class clsSaveButton, for example?

I suppose you want to extend the interface IButton right? So in that case just add Let/Get properties (if you just want to set the sheet name and use it internally in clsSaveButton then you will need only Let of course, and implement the interface.

I can pass the name into the clsSaveButton like this. that's ok. I can display the name of the worksheet.
But I can't use the name in the class cösSaveButton. For example, I cannot use the Range./ Cells application there

You can use the name within Worksheets collection, inside the code of the class Worksheets(m_sheetName).Range[a1]="Demo". Or the new property could by of type Worksheet directly and you can use it, so instead sheet name you will have the sheet itself inside the class.

I have adapted it all like this. Changed String to Worksheet, changed the Let statement to Set statement.  But it does not work

Private m_sheet As Worksheet + Public Property Set SheetObject(ByVal vNewValue As Worksheet) + Private Property Set IButton_SheetObject(ByVal vNewValue As Worksheet) Set m_sheet = vNewValue + Set oButtonSave.SheetObject = Worksheets(1)
